# How to filter objects by many to many attribute?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

Please help me to solve the following problem:

I have two models, for example:

```
class Student(model.Model): 
    first_name = models.Charfield()
    last_name = models.Charfield()

class Teacher(model.Model):
    first_name = models.Charfield()
    last_name = models.Charfield()
    subject = models.Charfield()
    students = models.ManyToManyField('Student')
```

A teacher object can have many students. When adding a new teacher, his students are immediately indicated, but a check must be performed for each student that this student is not tied to another teacher with the same subject. Please help me how to organize this check (I suppose using a filter).

I tried to use filter like Teacher.objects.filter(subject=self.subject),
but don't know how to check every student here

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is another teacher with the same subject with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Q

Teacher.objects.filter(
    ~Q(students__teacher__pk=F('pk')), students__teacher__subject=F('subject')
).annotate(
    student_id=F('students__pk'), other_teacher_id=F('students__teacher__pk')
)
```

This will obtain `Teacher`s for which there is at least one student with a different teacher with the same subject. The teacher will have extra attributes `student_id` and `other_teacher_id` which list the student and the other teacher for which the violation holds. The same `Teacher` can thus occur multiple times.

That being said, the modeling does not look very good: a teacher can only give one subject? You can make a junction table instead with:

```
class Student(model.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Teacher(model.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    students = models.ManyToManyField('Student', through='Subject')


class Subject(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstaint(
                fields=('subject', 'student'), name='subject_once_per_student'
            )
        ]
```

This will ensure that the same student can not take the same subject multiple times, and is enforced at the database level.

Comment: Thank you ! I have a question about students__teacher__pk=F('pk'). The check is carried out before saving the Teacher object, that is, what pk is meant here?

Comment: I would also like to clarify that the Student and Teacher models are used as an example, which is why they look so strange)